# Still having issues with the logout on tutorial

Tags: python, django

I followed the tutorial [Authentication](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html#logout) and I seem to still be having trouble with the website because when I clicked the arrow, I could not get the dropdown list to work and the logout still isn't there when I clicked on it.

I got this error when I was testing the Django Boards page.  This is causing me problems to see the dropdown list.  I followed the tutorial to the point and checked.  In order for the logout to work, I had to type in 127.0.0.1:8000/logout/ just so I could get the site to logout.

Error: GET /static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1 404 1683

Here's a tree listing of the files.
[image: Where my css, images, and js filess are kept]

Here's my base.html file, which may the root of the problem

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Django Boards{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
    {% block stylesheet %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Django Boards</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    {{ user.username }}
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change password</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            {% else %}
              <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Log in</a>
                <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Sign up</a>
              </form>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
          {% block breadcrumb %}
          {% endblock %}
        </ol>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>
    {% endblock body %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone show me what this error means (GET /static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1 404 1683) and how I should to fix the error I got and get the dropdown list to work?

Here's my urls.py file:

```
"""myproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from accounts import views as accounts_views
from boards import views


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^signup/$', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
        url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    
        url(r'^reset/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
                template_name='password_reset.html',
                email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
                subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt'
            ),
            name='password_reset'),
        url(r'^reset/done/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'),
            name='password_reset_done'),
        url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'),
            name='password_reset_confirm'),
        url(r'^reset/complete/$',
            auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html'),
            name='password_reset_complete'),
    
        url(r'^settings/password/$', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html'),
            name='password_change'),
        url(r'^settings/password/done/$',
            auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html'),
            name='password_change_done'),
    
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
        url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Here's my settings.py file.

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2hs@9wzrd6p2sre8(es78_ufx-6^wq7g+l@rk35p)vof6u4=y-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget_tweaks',
    
    'accounts',
    'boards'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: can you show the ```urls.py``` file and in ```settings.py``` file static file related code or can confirm that other static file are getting correctly

Comment: This isn't a problem with the logout, it's a problem with your static files. The tutorial asks you to create an app with `manage.py startapp accounts`, and then add `'accounts'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. You have placed your static directory in `myproject` instead. You could fix it by adding `myproject` to `INSTALLED_APPS` or by adding that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, but I recommend you follow the tutorial exactly, at least until you get it working.

Comment: Sure, I'll show you my urls.py file and settings.py file. Md Jewele Islam.

Comment: I managed to get the thing to work.  By recopying the bootstrap.min.css into the js folder, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `bootstrap.min.js` is located in a subfolder 'bootstrap' in js folder of static folder: `/static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js`.

In base.html, you have to change the call to static as

```html
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Moreover, since **base.html** is your root html file which will be called from your other pages by using `{% extends 'base.html' %}` on top of all your pages, I would recommend to include your js call in a block like

```html
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Then if you want to add extra js in other html page you can do for example:

```html
{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script src="{% static 'list_search.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

And you can do the same for your css file call in the  tag.

```html
{% block stylesheet %}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Peralta" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
{% endblock stylesheet %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not the actual file with name `bootstrap.min.js`. There is file with `bootstrap.min.css` inside js folder. I guess that is throwing 404.[image: Your image]

#### EDIT

I think you should consider using post request to logout from the session though its ok when learning.

Answer (score 0):

Go and Install Django-Bootstrap package than try to run your code.

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrap4'
    
    'accounts',
    'boards'
]
```

And insert the 'bootstrap4' in your "INSTALLED_APPS" in settings.py file.The way i did.